# How to fix: "Failed to resolve: com.android" error in Gradle on Android Studio IDE

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I worked on this project last week when I stopped working and closed it down everything was still working. Today I reopened it to continue working on it and it no longer works.  The only error that Android Studio gives me is `Failed to resolve: com.android` with a link to show in File. When I click on that link it brings me to the build.gradle file for the app. The build says

> Unresolved dependencies "Failed to resolve; com.androidShow in File".

Could someone please help me with this I am unsure how to solve this and have been trying various suggestions for a few hours now.

I am running Android Studio on Windows. My project is built in Java. This was working last I worked with it but as of today is not working. I have been trying to fix this for a few hours now following stackoverflow advice but none of it has worked so far. I have tried cleaning the project, rebuilding the project, syncing the project, Invalidating the cache and resetting Android Studio. I have also tried moving around the order of the calls in the Gradle file, changing some of the version numbers, changing the Gradle version, updating the SDK tools, and change the Offline work mode. I have included my Gradle code below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.android_app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.ic_support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.ic_support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.ic_support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.ic_support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.ic_support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.ic_support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: do first file-->Invalidate caches/Restart after clean and build project.

Comment: I have already tried this suggestion and it results in the same error response.

Comment: `'com.android.ic_support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'` the `ic_` there seems a typo

Comment: I just tried your suggestion of removing the ic_ and I still get the same error. I got those lines from a tutorial so I am unsure if they are correct or not and will keep this in mind as I keep trying other possible solution. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. The ic_ typo was only one part of the issue. I had to restart my whole machine, delete the .idea/libraries folder, as well as include a new file. Thank you for the help